# Dartdoc -> Exclude method body

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

I'm trying to generate documentation using dartdoc.

But when I run ... it includes method body e.g. codes inside a method.

How can I ask it to use only method signature ( exclude method body ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running `dartdoc --help` shows:

> ```
>     --[no-]include-source                         Show source code blocks.
>                                                   (defaults to on)
> ```